# Homomorphism between non abelian and abelian groups

Tags: group-theory

Is there nontrivial homomorphism example between non abelian and abelian groups?

Thank you

Comment: Please provide [additional context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960), which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Comment: There are plenty of examples, e.g. the sign homomorphism from the symmetric group on $n$ elements to a cyclic group of order $2$. In general all these morphisms factor through the quotient of the group modulo it derived subgroup so the corresponding projection is in essence the most fundamental of such homomorphisms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The canonical projection $G \times A \to A$, where $G$ is a nonabelian group and $A$ is a nontrivial abelian group.

Answer (score 3):

The parity function $\operatorname{sgn}:S_n \to \{\pm 1\}$ is a non-trivial homomorphism from a non-abelian group to an abelian group for $n \geq 3$.

Comment: Actually, this is the same example as the one given by Peter Melech, when you embed $S_n$ into $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ as permutation matrices.

Comment: @lhf I think you can also go the other way around, embedding $GL_n$ into a symmetric group of infinite order via [Cayley's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem)

Comment: Indeed,  good point!

Answer (score 1):

Yes for example the determinant:
$$\det:GL_n(\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow\{1,-1\}$$
where $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ is the group of invertible matrices over $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\{1,-1\}$ is the abelian cyclic group of order $2$